# Axis2 Skeleton not found?

Tags: apache-axis

I created a service for axis2 and implemented a service skeleton and a MessageReceiver for that service.

When i now want to call that service from a client, the Receiver on the server receives the call but in this code of the skeleton:

```
public void invokeBusinessLogic(
        org.apache.axis2.context.MessageContext msgContext,
        org.apache.axis2.context.MessageContext newMsgContext)
        throws org.apache.axis2.AxisFault {
    System.out.println("! !invokeBusinessLogic");
    try {            
        // get the implementation class for the Web Service
        Object obj = getTheImplementationObject(msgContext);
        System.out.println("2invokeBusinessLogic");
....
```

'2invokeBusinessLogic' will never be printed out. 
I checked the server on localhost:8080 and the service was correctly listed there.

So i want to call the service, the service Receiver gets the Request but does not find the skeleton?

There is no exception and i can not find the problem.

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

I see that the line `Object obj = getTheImplementationObject(msgContext)` is within a try/catch block. For troubleshooting purposes, try temporarily adding a catch section to that for `Throwable`, or at least catching `NoClassDefFoundError`. My recollection is that you can get a `NoClassDefFoundError` during that step if certain classes are missing from the JVM classpath, and that Axis2 won't log such an error anywhere.